# How to avoid 302 redirect for root folders on AWS S3 static site

Tags: amazon-s3, middleman

I have a (Middleman) blog hosted as a static site on S3: mysite.com/blog. I understand how [index document support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html) works. But I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid this scenario:

> if you exclude the trailing slash (/blog) ... If the blog object is not found, then it searches for an index document, blog/index.html. If that document is found, Amazon S3 returns a 302 Found.

I guess my question is how to create the "blog object", or what do I need to do so that neither /blog nor /blog/ result in a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, the directory_indexes helper in Middleman solves for this: https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/pretty-urls/

It will allow you to reach your blog's index page from both `mysite.com/blog/` and `mysite.com/blog` by creating a `blog` folder with `index.html` at the root.

I've had success with "pretty urls" by using the above method, coupled with the s3_sync gem: https://github.com/fredjean/middleman-s3_sync

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't notice that feature of Middleman. In the meantime I got what I wanted with an Nginx rewrite, but I'll consider this for future cases.